# Dismiss dropdown on outside click using vanilla JavaScript and ARIA roles

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to create a very basic dropdown menu but am unable to get the hide on outside click part right. I've gone through several iterations yet always end up unable to dismiss it correctly or close other opened dropdowns when another is activated. Here is my latest variation.

```js
function Menu(trigger) {
  let expanded = trigger.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === "true" || false;
  let menu = trigger.nextElementSibling;

  trigger.setAttribute("aria-expanded", !expanded);
  menu.hidden = !menu.hidden;
}

const menuTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-trigger");

menuTriggers.forEach((menuTrigger) => {
  menuTrigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    Menu(menuTrigger);
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="menu-trigger" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
<ul class="menu" hidden>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="">Books</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="">Authors</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-link menu-link-separator" href="">Genres</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="">Themes</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to listen for a mousedown event on the window object to detect the off-click and only close the drop down menu if the event.target is not contained by the drop down menu itself.

```js
function Menu(trigger)
{
    let expanded = trigger.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === "true" || false;
    let menu = trigger.nextElementSibling;
    trigger.setAttribute("aria-expanded", !expanded);
    menu.hidden = !menu.hidden;
    if(!menu.hidden)
    {
        setTimeout(() =>
        {
            let eventType = "mousedown";
            let handler = (e) =>
            {
                if (trigger !== e.target && !menu.contains(e.target))
                {
                    Menu(trigger);
                }
                window.removeEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
            };
            window.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
        }, 0);
    }
}

const menuTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-trigger");
menuTriggers.forEach((menuTrigger) =>
{
    menuTrigger.addEventListener("click", () =>
    {
        Menu(menuTrigger);
    });
});
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block">
<button class="menu-trigger" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
<ul class="menu" hidden>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="https://amazon.com">Books</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="">Authors</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-link menu-link-separator" href="">Genres</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="">Themes</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm gonna try and handle the outside click inside the `Menu()` function in order to establish a clearer component definition.

Comment: No problem, I edited the answer, moving the code into the `Menu()` function.

Comment: Tried it right now. Thanks for the tips! From what I could gather the `setTimeout()` is not necessary; is that correct? And another condition needs to be added as part of `handler()` in order for it to allow links to be followed: `!trigger.contains(e.target) && !menu.contains(e.target)`.

Comment: You may find that the setTimeout is necessary in some situations. It prevents the button click from also firing the mousedown event during the same click. Weird, but I've seen that happen in some browsers. The `ul` element is a block element that invisibly spans the whole screen width. To address this, I wrapped the html inside of an `inline-block`. You'll figure out the details; this was just a start for you.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Indeed, it does seem that preventing multiple events from firing is necessary, either though `setTimeout()` or various conditional statements.